# passing special character in jax-rs webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have two jax-rs webservices: **WS1** and **WS2**.

Also I have an html form that user add some text and when click submit button call WS1 or WS2 and send an xml file via post.

The xml file look like:

```
<documents>
<document> some text 1 </document>
<document> some text 2 </document>
</documents>
```

When I call **ws1** or **ws2** from html form, xml file passes without problem.

But when I try to call **ws1** from **ws2**, I can't send xml file which contains special characters in element "document". (don't send all xml file)

So my question is how can I pass xml file that contains special characters or how can replace all special characters?

**Call wb1**

```
 public String sendPost(String value) throws Exception {
            String url = "http://localhost:8084//wb1";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            String urlParameters = "xmlinput=" + value;

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            java.io.BufferedOutputStream wr = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            //response
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();


            return response.toString();
        }
```

**wb1:**

```
 @POST
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public String getXml(@FormParam("xmlinput") String xmlinput) throws Exception {
     //some code
 }
```

**EDIT:**

for example I have this string:

> RT @*CEJA*: CEJA President @BartoliniMatteo with S&amp;D COMAGRI
>   coordinator @paolodecastro. @EP_Agriculture @TheProgressives
>   http://t.co/65xi4…

I want to replace &amp; with black space.

I try with **String.replaceAll("\W", " ");** but 1) replace only &; etc 2) I want to keep links without modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Apache Commons Lang [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils#escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) for requests, and #unescapeXml for responses.

Comment: I try escapeXml and escapeHtml3,4 but now receive an empty string. In actualy I prefer to replace this special characters with empty string!